# cant acess video adzone (revive adserver)

Tags: php, advertisement-server

I want to show video on my jw player using revive adserver, but when i click video zone it shows me 404 error, but im sure folder and files exists and it has right path, can anyone help me? I searched and tried everything for 5 hours, I asked it on revive adserver's forum but nobody answered too.

Comment: I had same issue and finally I was not able to solve it.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happened due to file permissions is not correct.

Actually revive adserver will not generate Video Invocation tag, we have to generate by own. In JW player site they provided some document about how to generate tag for that.